# Python counting number of rows n a csv

Tags: python, csv, count

Hi I tried the following code to count the number of rows in a csv file :

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\\Users')
csv_file = open("count_rows.csv", "rb")
row_count = sum(1 for row in csv_file.read())
csv_file.close()
print (row_count)
```

The above code displays 18 as the result when the file has only 3 rows.

Any suggestions?

Thanks so much

Comment: Why did you open the file with `'rb'`? That is for binary files. You just want `'r'`.

Answer (score 1):

The following line is not iterate lines, but each byte of the file content. (Iterating string object yields single-character strings)

```
row_count = sum(1 for row in csv_file.read())
```

To iterate lines, just iterate over the file object:

```
row_count = sum(1 for row in csv_file)
```

Here's a slighly modified version:

```
# Using `with` statement, you don't need to close manually.
# Use raw string literal: you can avoid escape
with open(r"C:\Users\count_rows.csv") as csv_file:  # `r`: use text mode
    row_count = sum(1 for row in csv_file)
    print(row_count)
```

Answer (score 1):

`csv_file` should be an iterator -- you can just run `sum(1 for row in csv_file)`.

Also, it is best practice to open the file with [a context manager](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/):

```
with open('count_rows.csv') as buff:
  row_count = sum(1 for _ in buff)

print(row_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

any text file (incl. csv) can have lines counted as follows:

```
>>> fname = "file.txt"
>>> with open(fname) as f:
...     for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
...         pass
... print i
```

`enumerate` generates numbers for all lines, assigning it to `i`.

When the loop terminates, `i` holds the number of lines. Note, that the `enumerate` has the `1`
argument used, to set up numbering from 1. (thanks falsetru)

Comment: If you use `enumerate(f, 1)`, `i` will hold the number of lines. BTW, if the file is empty (0 byte), the last statement will raise `NameError`.